# Binding style to the field only for mobile screens

Tags: css, vue.js, bulma

I am trying to make a navbar using Bulma and Vue.js and Bulma has this thing  where when navbar collapse to the hamburg menu, the dropdown list inside that is already in `display: block;` mode. So I found a workaround but it also apply the same style to all screen sizes.

I then tried to bind style like this in the template only

```
<div class="navbar-dropdown" :style="@media screen and (max-width: 900px){display: this.displayBlockAcad}">
```

which gave me this error

```
invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){display: this.displayBlockAcad}
```

I made [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1uk3r/t9xos61k/12/) for demo. If you remove `@media screen and (max-width: 900px)` from line 26, jsfiddle will run without error but `is-hoverable` class in line 22 will not work anymore. Is there a way I can make dropdown hoverable in desktop screens while using my own methods for media screens

Answer (score 1):

You are making mistake, for binding styles we have to pass an object not string. :style is not a valid binding attribute. if you want to declare a @media expression then write in between style tag or within a css file, and give a unique class and assign it to your element.

```
v-bind:style="{key:property}" // object passing
```

Here is link how you can bind your styles in vue.js
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: can you elaborate on `give a unique class and assign it to your element.` because I am having hard time in figuring it out how to change styles dynamically for media screens.

Comment: Please understand, @media is a css markup to detect width of window in stylesheet. but in javascript you have much flexibility so you can change it by if( screen.width > 800px) document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display= 'block'; That's it. mission accomplish... here is example https://jsfiddle.net/ssorabh/w5truy6m/14/
Don't confused about media tags in css with javascript way of detecting media..
Understand, the inheritance of styles, external styles can overide by inline styles automatically.

Comment: If you are developing a web based development, you can also check by using window.innerWidth > 800 and so on.

Comment: Ok, thats the answer to what I asked, but I am still not getting what I wanted to achieve. I was able to do the same thing as your jsfiddle with my one  if i remove `@media screen and (max-width: 900px)`, The problem was by doing that my `is-hoverable` class wouldn't respond. I really thankful for your help thus far but can you tell me how can I make dropdown hoverable for desktop screens?

Comment: why don't you just create two different html element, one with click trigger and another with hover trigger? and by using conditional rendering v-if put conditions
<div v-if="window.innerWidth > 800">
  hover element display
</div>
<div v-else>
  clicked element renders
</div> 
Why are you making things complicated...

Comment: That's a nice idea, I'll give it a try